# Convert Azure Cosmos Db SQL-API statement that gets generated in a foreach loop to parameterized statement

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to convert the below working COSMOS DB SQL statement to a parametrized statement in SQL for COSMOS DB.

The part that I am struggling with is creating the parameters for the parameterized query in the for each loop.

As an example I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` object with key value pairs that contain the values that I need to search for.

I have built the query by adding the Key value pairs form the `Dictionary<string,string>` object to the SQL statement in a foreach loop but I would like to convert it to a parameterized statement for safety.

So I need to convert the below query to be a parameterized query for the index Key and values that I am searching on but I am not sure how to go about it.

```
var searchDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
searchDictionary.Add("Name", "Bob");
searchDictionary.Add("Surname", "Builder");

var Institiute = "test";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append($"SELECT top 100 * FROM c WHERE c.college =@'{Institiute}'");
foreach (var item in request.IndexData)
{
    sb.Append($" and c.indexData['{item.Key}'] = '{item.Value}'");
}

var sqlQueryText = sb.ToString();
```